# Installing Ubuntu 13.x on HP Split X2

Tags: installation, 13.04

I want to install ubuntu on my HP Split X2 with intel i3 4010Y processor.

I tried loading using the usb stick. Boot is working fine. but it seems to problem with graphics. Login screen is not getting displayed.

I am not able to check the logs also since the screen is blank.

Any suggestions for checking logs during boot?

Answer (score 2):

I know it would be largely experimental, but you can try Ubuntu 14.04.  I managed to install that on my Pavilion 11 x2 (a 2-in-1 device).

[Ubuntu 14.04 on HP Pavilion 11.6" x2 2-in-1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200671&p=12905579#post12905579)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to kernel options on GRUB (e key)

```
acpi_backlight=vendor
```

If you decide to install it you should add it to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

I have a Split with i5 but Touchpad doesn't work at all